# visual studio 2010 - jumping to method definition with the mouse

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Moving from years of work on intellij to VS2010 (with resharper ) I cant stop clicking the mouse scroll wheel in order to jump to function or variable definition (as in intellij or F12) only to find that this feature does not exist.

Is there a way to set this feature ?
Is there a diffent way to do it with the mouse ? 
Thanks.

EDIT - Thanks guys - but I wanted to set the mouse scroll press

Comment: right click , go to definition......

Comment: The number of people who actually didn't read the question amuses me.

Answer (score 1):

F12 will go to definition. Power productivity tools comes with a ctrl+click to go to definition.

Power productivity tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Comment: well if you have to push CTRL so you do ctrl+click, might as well just press F12 :)

Answer (score 0):

or F12 ------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the variable and you will have an option to see definition:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're really adamant about it, you can check here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25369/Forward-Backward-navigation-with-the-mouse-thumb-b to put you in the track for a do-it-yourself approach